# Xampp Localhost bug

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, localhost

I inheritted some legacy code(project). I have to put it on localhost. I'm using xampp. When i access it, the localhost return me:

> 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.

The project was built under codeigniter framework. Any other project works fine on localhost. If I access localhost/test, it works. But when i access this project it gives me the error. 
So I'm looking for any tips or hints from you guys. What can I check or what can i do ? I'm, looking forward for answers from you. Thx
.htaccess code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
    php_value default_charset utf-8 
    php_flag display_startup_errors off
    php_flag display_errors off
    php_flag html_errors off
    php_value docref_root 0
    php_value docref_ext 0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value default_charset utf-8 
    php_flag display_startup_errors off
    php_flag display_errors off
    php_flag html_errors off
    php_value docref_root 0
    php_value docref_ext 0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckSpelling On
</IfModule>
#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLRequireSSL
#SSLVerifyDepth 1
#SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
```

Comment: Are you sure the XAMPP has mod_rewrite setup and is correctly rewriting the URLs. I'm assuming you've checked all the codeigniter config files for paths which may need updating?

Comment: if you reffer to : "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" . it is loaded

Comment: And you get a 404 for all pages? Is there a .htaccess file included with the code?

Comment: I posted my htaccess code

Comment: My apologies. Have you tried accessing index.php directly, what are the results? I mean via http://localhost/index.php

Comment: that was the 3 or 4 attempt

Comment: I really need more information. Is it a standard 404 error you are getting, does the index.php even exist? Or are you seeing a CodeIgniter styled 404 page?

Comment: I get rid of index.php from config. What I realized that, if I accessed localhost/path1/path2/myproject , it doesnt work, but if I accessed just localhost, it works. Any ideea why?

Comment: No idea without knowing more about the setup or the config file, or index file I'm afraid.

Comment: remove "CheckSpelling On". It was the only directive I used and Xampp crashed (Server Error 500)